# Loading 'view' to a direct tab from controller

Tags: codeigniter, tabs, loading

I have a code that lies in the third 'gallery' tab. 'Wall' is the active tab when the page loads.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#my-wall">Wall</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#gallery">Gallery-Photos</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I'd like to load the view from the controller directly to the 'gallery' tab. Is it possible to simply add the tab's ID as follow in code igniter or is there another way:

```
$this->load->view('wall#gallery'), $data);
```

Appreciate all feedback.

Comment: you can dynamically add the class active to the `<li>` tag when calling the related function from controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily like this.

Remove **active class** from all tabs and send a specific variable to view. Base on that variable add the condition to active your desired tab.

```
$data['active_tab'] = 'gallery';
$this->load->view('wall', $data);
```

View

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li <?php if($active_tab == 'my-wall'){ echo "class='active'";}?> ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#my-wall">Wall</a></li>
      <li <?php if($active_tab == 'profile'){ echo "class='active'";}?>  ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
      <li <?php if($active_tab == 'gallery'){ echo "class='active'";}?> ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#gallery">Gallery-Photos</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! Will let you know if I have a follow up.

Comment: @dreamerdan my pleasure :)